# Is it possible to do 2 way data-binding on meteor

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor.. I am looking for a way to perform 2 way databinding between a model/collection to template. It is my understanding that when the contents of a collection change, the template reacts to this change and updates itself. However, how to automatically the collection when a user types, for example, in a textbox?

Comment: Have you seen rivetsjs?

Comment: You might want to consider the aldeed:autoform package. http://autoform.meteor.com/updateaf

Answer (score 13):

You could use the [template events binding](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events)

e.g if you have

**html**

```
<template name="home">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="{{text}}"/>
</template>
```

**client js**

```
Template.home.text = function() {
    return MyCollection.findOne({_id:"1"}).text;
}

Template.home.events({
    'change input[name=text]':function(event,context) {
        MyCollection.update(_id, {$set:{text:event.target.value}});
    }
});
```

So that will make it update as soon as the textbox loses focus/enter is pressed/etc

If you want to use the submit button & for something a bit cooler have a look at the [controllers branch of meteor on github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/controllers) for the
easy forms system currently in the works to easen this up a bit.