# MeteorJS - how to introduce two-way bindings

Tags: angularjs, meteor

Is there a way to introduce two-way bindings in a Meteor application, without adding AngularJS?
I would like to have a functionality in my input elements (text field, drop down, checkbox, etc...) where a changed value is saved back to the database automatically in response to a blur, item changed, or other such events. I understand, that Angular has nothing to do with auto-saving, but, having a two-way bindings in Meteor would bring it one step closer to my "ideal" scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/package/autoform) package. If that does too much for your needs, the simple way is detailed here on this SO answer: [Is it possible to do 2 way data-binding on meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444121/is-it-possible-to-do-2-way-data-binding-on-meteor)